# How do I make window splits maintain consistent sizing with the current as large and others as small

Tags: vim, neovim

The idea is to do something similar to what [Golden Ratio](https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio) (the vim plugin) does. But instead of sizing to a "golden ratio", I want to set a specific size to the unselected windows.

Ex:

```
# Window 1 selected
----------------------
|        |   |   |   |
|        |   |   |   |
|   1    | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|        |   |   |   |
|        |   |   |   |
----------------------

# Window 3 selected
----------------------
|   |   |        |   |
|   |   |        |   |
| 1 | 2 |    3   | 4 |
|   |   |        |   |
|   |   |        |   |
----------------------
```

Here's what I've written so far (It's just a WIP):

```
function g:ResizeWindow()
  let tabs = gettabinfo()
  let current_tabnr = tabpagenr()
  let current_window = win_getid()

  let tab = filter(tabs, 'v:val.tabnr == current_tabnr')[0]

  for window in tab.windows
    if window != current_window
      call win_gotoid(window)
      exe 'vertical resize' 20
    endif
  endfor

  call win_gotoid(current_window)
  let current_window_size = &columns - ((len(tab.windows) - 1) * 20)
  exe 'vertical resize' current_window_size
endfunction

autocmd WinNew,WinEnter * :call g:ResizeWindow()
```

To test, you can open a single buffer and just `:vsp` it several times. Then when you navigate the windows, it seems to work in most case but occasionally one of the windows collapses in an inconsistent way. It's much smaller than the rest. Usually this happens as I navigate from the left to right... and the back from right to left.

Any ideas on what's wrong with this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

super interesting function!

Here's a working version:

```
function g:ResizeWindow()
  let tabs = gettabinfo()
  let current_tabnr = tabpagenr()
  let current_window = win_getid()

  let tab = filter(tabs, 'v:val.tabnr == current_tabnr')[0]

  let small_size = 5

  for window in tab.windows
    if window == current_window
      let size = &columns - ((len(tab.windows) - 1) * small_size) - (len(tab.windows) - 1)
    else
      let size = small_size
    endif
    noautocmd call win_gotoid(window)
    exe 'noautocmd vertical resize ' . size
  endfor

  call win_gotoid(current_window)
endfunction

set winwidth=1
set winminwidth=1
autocmd WinNew,WinEnter * :call g:ResizeWindow()
```

---

#### Explanation

I did quite a few changes to your initial WIP, here are the main problems your code encountered:

- The function was called recursively: call of the function `win_gotoid` was triggering the autocmd. So this was messing up all the sizes
- The default minimum window size (`minwinwidth`) and default window size (`winwidth`) were messing up with the size you applied
- You resized the current window as last, which squished the window on the right
- Your main window size calculation didn't take in account the window separators

---

#### Disclaimer

This function breaks if there is an horizontal split on one window!

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for the detailed explanation (and updating the code to work). I was not aware of the `noautocmd` function. This is great! I'm not sure setting `minwinwidth` and `winwidth` is needed though. I've tried removing them and it still worked fine. Besides, aren't the defaults set to `1`?

Comment: For me, the default `winminwidth` is 1 indeed, but the default `windwidth` is 20. This breaks the function if you go crazy and there are so many windows that the main window should shrink below 20. But in normal cases, that's not apparent

Comment: Well @Nathan, I edited my answer, it's kind of disappointing to see how easy it could have been!

Comment: Nooo. Please remove the revised solution. This will not work. As mentioned in my original post, my function was a WIP. There are several things that I'll need to add. One of which is recognizing when the widow/buffer belongs to 3d-party plug-in like Mundo, NERDTree, etc. Setting a `winminwidth` and `winminheight` will effect these windows.